# How do I annotate/label holidays in a Matplotlib lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Can someone help me with the annotation of holidays in a matplotlib (or Seaborn) lineplot? I tried a couple of loops but I couldn't figure it out.

This is how my DF looks like (Aantal = Count, Feestdag = Holiday):

[image: Dummy Dataset]

My goal is to accomplish this kind of plot:

[image: Plot with annotation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my question thanks to @Anwarvic! I made this loop (with ax.annotate) to make it update automatically.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
dummy2019.plot(ax=ax)

for index, row in dummy2019.iterrows():
    if type(row['Feestdag']) is str:
        datum = index
        aantal = row['Aantal']
        feestdag = row['Feestdag']
        ax.annotate(feestdag, xy=(index, aantal),  xycoords='data',
                xytext=(80, -30), textcoords='offset points',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ax.annotate()` method. Here is a full example:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

days = range(365)
# generate random numbers between 4000 and 5200
values = [4000+(random.random() * (5200 - 4000)) for _ in range(365)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(days, values)
plt.ylim(3000, 5400)
ax.set_xticks(days[::32])
ax.set_xticklabels(["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
                    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"])
plt.show()
```

Which produces this plot:
[image]

Now, let's annotate some points in this graph. We can do that using `ax.annotate()` method before `plt.show()` like so:

```
...
# annotate some points:
ax.annotate("100th data point", (days[100], values[100]), xytext=(days[100], values[100]-1000),
     arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="angle3,angleA=0,angleB=-90"))

ax.annotate("200th data point", (days[200], values[200]), xytext=(days[200], values[200]-1000),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05))

# didn't use any arrow styles (just to show how it should look like)
ax.annotate("300th data point", (days[300], values[300]))
plt.show()
```

And this produces the following graph:
[image]

Using `ax.annotate()` is easy... the following are the arguments that I've used:

- The first argument is the message text
- The second argument is the coordinates of the point you want to annotate
- The third argument is the location where the text will be written.
- The fourth argument is how the arrow should look like.

Check the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) for `ax.annotate()` for more info.